# Style figure captions and table captions differently

Tags: captions

Using the `caption` package I can set the style for captions for *all* floating elements in my document:

```
\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
```

Now, suppose I want my *figures* captioned like this, but my *tables* captioned in **bold**. How can I achieve this?

The documentation tells me I can define two *caption styles*, and switch between them manually every time I insert a figure or table using the `\captionsetup` command. Is there a better way?

Comment: If I remember correctly, a `\captionsetup[figure]{...}` outside the `figure` environment acts globally, so its setting are persistent, the same for `\captionsetup[table]{}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That did the trick perfectly, thank you! Mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I am pretty sure it's a duplicate but I am too lazy to look for it ;-)